# Проблема с transition на элементе слайдера с position: absolute;

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать слайдер на сайте. Не получалось сделать чтобы блоки выходили за границу блока-хранилища и решил использовать *position:absolute*.
Проблема в том, что при изменении значения *left* блок не ездит а просто перемещается. Нашел в интернете такую команду:

```
transition: all 10s linear;
```

не помогло

jquery:

```
$('.slider').on('click', '.glyphicon-chevron-left', function(e){
let wrapperWidth = -$('.sliders-wrapper')[0].clientWidth;
$('.slider-image').eq(0).css({'left':''+100+'px', 'opacity':'0'});
});
```

прозрачность срабатывает а left нет. просто прыгает

Comment: Научитесь уже в свои вопросы добавлять [mcve]

Comment: Задайте left начальное значение

Comment: спасибо сработало